# JSP/servlet processing in webview

Tags: java, android, servlets, android-webview, webviewclient

I am trying to convert a full website into android app using webview but I am stuck where server processing is required.

I click a link on `html` page it goes to `servlet`(I've created a `WAR` and deployed it on Apache Tomcat server") and the result is redirected to a `JSP` page.

Everything's working fine in full website but in android `webview` when I click "the link" an error message comes up :

> Cycle Detected : your request is prohibited beacuse it would cause a cycle

I assume `webview` doesn't support server side processing.
 How can I make this thing work?

Answer (score 0):

Just go get your question right: do you want to put a web-application sandbox locally on your android device - that is having a local HTTP server on your android and use WebView as a "client" view poiting to a locally running server?

On which tomcat did you deploy your war file? Is this tomcat running somere in your network, I mean on another physical machine?

A WebView acts as an embedded browser-instance. So you can try to open a default browser on your android device and navigate there to your tomcat server and check if your website is doing well there. Maybe you forgotten to enable java-script execution in webView

In case you run your android in an emulator and run a tomcat-server on the same machine you have to access it via

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/...
```

rather than

```
http://localhost:8080/...
```

port number may differ.

Comment: Well if u didn't get the question right u might not have the solution either. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2168407 It's not just gPlusHub that is confused by your question.  .. maybe you can clarify.

Comment: All i want to do is get the values from database using java servlet and display it in my webview. for now everthing is deployed on the **local tomcat server**. Only database resides at a remote server.
Click Link-->Servlet(local server)-->Database(remote server)-->
JSP(local server)-->webview(android)

One thing I came to know it cannot access the localhost:8080 i.e. an error came up but how should I display the values from  the database in android web view
Plz tell if more clarification is required.

Comment: @gPlusHub I tried using http://10.0.2.2:8080/ but the page keeps on loading but nothing is displayed.

Comment: have you enabled JavaScript in the WebView?

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: are you trying on emulator? then please open a browser-app on the emulator and enter www.google.com - does it work? then open (in same browser) your app: http://10.0.2.2:8080 - does it work?

Comment: yes www.google.com is working fine on the app-browser but still it is not opening 10.0.2.2:8080 now it prints "internal error - server connection terminated" . Is there any other way i can access servlet on the local host.?

Comment: ah fine. Are you sure your tomcat is running on port 8080? Can you open a browser on YOUR MACHINE WHERE (I guess same machine where you run your emulator) tomcat is running and point it to http: //localhost:[port] ? do you see results there?

Comment: yes tomcat is running on port 8080. and yes i can open browser on my local machine and getting the required results.

Comment: can there be a problem with the proxy? although I've entered all the proxy details in the emulator and I'm able to access google and other websites from the local android browser.

Comment: maybe that's the issue, you actually dont require proxy settings in your emulator! turn them off and allow direct access without proxy. When disables, check again if www.google.com is reachable from emulator then try the address 10.0.2.2:8080, dont forget to prefix with http:// also please refer here for more information how emulator maps IPs: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: phew! finally it's working proxy was the issue. Actually I do need proxy to access internet on the emulator so cannot disable it. I cannot reach google when proxy is disabled but surely can access my machine's local host. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: nice. Additionally, you can add additional configuration to your proxy-settings to skip certain/local addresses, just add the 10.0.2.2 in there so you can have internet and local access sidebyside.

Comment: @comeGetSome I tried searching for bypassing proxy server for local addresses on emulator but couldn't find a convincing solution. Can u help.?